# how to implement multi range calender with multi color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want https://npm.runkit.com/react-date-range this type of calendar view in flutter is there any library or method to implement calendar like this. I already tried https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker this library but this provide only single color range.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is this plugin called (date range picker).
apply this plugin in your pubspec.yaml file and import it as dateRangePicker.

Here is the snippet of the sample code

```
 Future displayDateRangePicker(context) async {
final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePick.showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialFirstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:7)),
    initialLastDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
    lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    selectableDayPredicate: checkLimit
    );
```

Comment: Hello there, i think you might be wrong by this we can only achieve only one range with one color i need dynamic color in more than one range.